# How to delete some of AWS S3 file after some days

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do we delete some(not all) files present in AWS S3 bucket after few days? But approach must be followed using Lifecycle Configuration.

Comment: Is this what you're thinking of ? - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 2):

Use [S3 REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTlifecycle.html) to create a lifecycle object and specify `Filter` that identifies objects to which the lifecycle rule applies.

Example

```
<LifecycleConfiguration>
    <Rule>
        <ID>id1</ID>
        <Filter>
            <Prefix>documents/</Prefix>
            <-- OR -->
            <Tag>old-documents-tag</Tag>
        </Filter>
        <Status>Enabled</Status>
        <Expiration>
            <Days>60</Days>
        </Expiration>
        <NoncurrentVersionExpiration>     
            <NoncurrentDays>30</NoncurrentDays>    
        </NoncurrentVersionExpiration>
    </Rule>
</LifecycleConfiguration>
```

Comment: How I configured this XML to my application? How I configured this XML to s3 bucket lifecycle policy?

Comment: @VivekSharma In the Amazon S3 console, click your bucket, go to the **Management** tab and you can configure **Lifecycle**. See: [Object Lifecycle Management - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html)